# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' how do i import firebase 10.3.1 in module.ts file in ionic angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I started a project with `"@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",` with `"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",` and `"firebase": "^10.3.1"` the app frankly has been running very smoothly as expected. but when I tried uploading an image it throws an error in the console which is being very hard for me to understand.

I don't know if firebase has change several things since the version 10 release on like the version 9

this is my module sample here

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 

import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment.prod'; 
import { provideStorage, } from '@angular/fire/storage'; 
import {  provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app'; 
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { indexedDBLocalPersistence, initializeAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getApp } from 'firebase/app';  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideAuth(() => {
        if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
            return initializeAuth(getApp(), {
                persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
            });
        } else {
            return getAuth();
        }
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()), 
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()), 
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)), 
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

when I import storage `import { Storage } from '@angular/fire/storage';`

and make a reference in the constructor `private storage: Storage`

this is the error I get from the console below, and after that the app now goes plane white screen nothing to display

```
core.mjs:11458 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
```